# download.file from url without specifying filename using R

Tags: r

Am trying to download a file from a url. If I manually download and unzip it works fine, however, using download.file the zip is corrupt. I wonder if it is something to do with manually specifying the file name. Why is this neccesary when using the download.file function? Is it not possible to simply specify a url and folder and it download the file as it is named on the server?

```
##using R
##download url
url <- 'https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/denmark-shapefile/at_download/file'

download.file(url, destfile ='Denmark_shapefile.zip')

unzip(zipfile = 'Denmark_shapefile.zip', exdir = '.')
```

Unzip fails as the file is corrupt

Comment: You can use `temp <- tempfile();
download.file(url, temp)`

Comment: It downloads with this, but I can't find to where, it isn't the working directory. Is there a way of specifying the directory but not the file name?

Answer (score 2):

`destfile ='Denmark_shapefile.zip'` is only specifying the name the downloaded file should have. You can write anything you want in there.

Your code works for me exactly as it is, but you could try using this download statement instead of yours which is specified for writing and is binary safe.

```
download.file(url, destfile ='Denmark_shapefile.zip', mode='wb', cacheOK=FALSE)
```

Comment: Why do I need to specify anything? The file on the server has a name, can't it just download as it is? I think this renaming of the file is what is causing the unzip to fail.

Comment: I just tried executing your code 1:1 as it is and it works completely fine for me. It unzipped it into the same directory as `Denmark_shapefile.zip` is

Comment: I get the error 'Warning message:
In unzip(zipfile = "Denmark_shapefile.zip", exdir = ".") :
  internal error in 'unz' code'

Comment: Could you please give me the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Warning message:
In unzip(zipfile = "Denmark_shapefile.zip", exdir = ".") :
  internal error in 'unz' code

Comment: What do you mean 1:1?

Comment: With that I just meant I copied your code without editing.
Could you try using this download statement instead?
`download.file(url, destfile ='Denmark_shapefile.zip', mode='wb', cacheOK=FALSE)`

Comment: @B_K is your problem solved?

Comment: Mostly, thanks for your help. Still not sure how to download without specifying a filename (i.e. download the file as it is named on the server)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is,

```
    url <- 'https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-
files/denmark-shapefile/at_download/file'
```

Your working directory is were files are downloaded

```
library(stringr)
fold = str_replace_all(getwd(), '/', '\\\\')
```

A random file name is assigned to zip file.

```
fil = tempfile(pattern = "file", tmpdir = fold, fileext = '.zip')
download.file(url, fil, mode = 'wb')
```